# Expected Sum of n numbers after m random opeartions on n numbers.

Tags: probability, expectation

I have been given $25$ objects numbered from $1$ to $25$ and a set $S = \{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2\}$. I have to choose a random number from the given set and add it to all the objects. I have to do this $5$ times. What will be the expected sum of all objects after all $5$ turns?

Comment: are you sampling form S with or without replacement

Comment: The "without replacement" answer should be clear. It turns out that the expected value is the same if the sampling from $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ is done with replacement, with all numbers equally likely.

Comment: Sorry, Sampling should be done with replacement

Comment: @AndréNicolas you're completely right didn't even notice there were five numbers in S. oops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am letting $S_{i}$ indicate the random number from S in draw i. So we want to find 
$$E\left(\sum_{j=1}^{25}\left(j+\sum_{i=1}^{5}S_{i}\right)\right)=E\left(\sum_{j=1}^{25}j+25\sum_{i=1}^{5}S_{i}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{25}j+25\sum_{i=1}^{5}E(S_{i})$$

where we note that $\sum_{j=1}^{25}j=\frac{25(26)}{2}=325$ so we have are expected value of sum will be

$$=325+25\sum_{i=1}^{5}E(S_{i})$$
where 
$$E(S_{i})=\frac{1}{5}(-2-1+0+1+2)=0$$
And since sampling with replacement this is true for i=1,..,5 so finally we have
$$=325+25\sum_{i=1}^{5}0=325+25(0)=325$$

If anyone sees any mistakes or ways this can be done better please comment.